# grep for an ANSI escape code

Tags: grep, escape-characters

I've checked out a lot of links on how to `grep` individual escape characters or literal strings, but I just cannot get them to combine to find the background-red ANSI escape sequence `^[41m`, even typing the `^[` as both <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl+[</kbd> and the two literal characters <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and using both the `-E` and `-F` flags.

The raw bytes I am trying to find, given by `hexdump` are:

```
1b 5b 33 37 6d 1b 5b 34 31 6d 30 2e 30 30 25
```

Where this corresponds to `WHITE FOREGROUND` `RED BACKGROUND` `0.00%`. I'm producing these codes with [Python's colorama package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) and `Fore.WHITE+Back.RED`, just in case anyone is curious.

So, what is the secret I am missing?

Comment: What is the problem of `\grep '\^\[41m'` ?

Comment: Doesn't work for me with GNU grep 2.16.

Comment: Can you attach the part of `^[41m` content of the target file ? Use `hexdump -C <filename>`. I have no problem to grep it with GNU grep 2.16.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> but I just cannot get them to combine to find the background-red ANSI
>   escape sequence **^[41m**

If you use `vim` to open this file, you will know it's not **^[41m**, instead it's **^[[41m**, which **^[** navigate by arrow key as a set:

[image]

`1b` is **Escape** represent by single escape character `^[` which can be invoked by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> follow by <kbd>Esc</kbd>. `^[` look like 2 characters but it's not, it's single:

```
xb@dnxb:~/Downloads/grep$ ascii 1b
ASCII 1/11 is decimal 027, hex 1b, octal 033, bits 00011011: called ^[, ESC
Official name: Escape

xb@dnxb:~/Downloads/grep$
```

Do this (Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> follow by <kbd>Esc</kbd> to create `^[`, then continuously type `\[41m`):

```
xb@dnxb:~/Downloads/grep$ hexdump -C /tmp/2
00000000  1b 5b 33 37 6d 1b 5b 34  31 6d 30 2e 30 30 25 0a  |.[37m.[41m0.00%.|
00000010
xb@dnxb:~/Downloads/grep$ \grep '^[\[41m' /tmp/2
0.00%
xb@dnxb:~/Downloads/grep$ \grep '^[\[41m' /tmp/2 | hexdump -C
00000000  1b 5b 33 37 6d 1b 5b 34  31 6d 30 2e 30 30 25 0a  |.[37m.[41m0.00%.|
00000010
xb@dnxb:~/Downloads/grep$
```

Ensure you escape grep by prefix `\` to avoid its alias `--color` affect:

[image]

**[Alternative]:**

1. `\grep -P '\e\[41m'` (Credit: OP's comment)
2. `\grep '^[\[41m'` , which use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> follow by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> to create `^[`. Useful when backspace in my keyboard is not 0x08, but i can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> follow by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (^H get from `ascii 08`) to produce it.

Comment: Thank you for that - I see the problem was mostly me not realising there was both a `[` from the `^[` and the literal `[`. Since my initial post, I'd also discovered that `\grep -P "\e\[41m"` is an alternative.

Comment: `\grep $'^\x1b\[41m'` will work without perl regex or inserting a literal escape sequence, so it is editor friendly and works on mac.